# Xamarin crossplatform ipv6 ping

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, networking, ping

i'm looking for a crossplatform solution to do a ping to my dyndns at dynv6, which is bound to my ipv6 adress, port 8443 is open through SSL.

i want my device to check if the adress is available for further webrequests. simple webrequests are possible too but those have answer times of 3 seconds even if they are just answered with OK().

so i thought of Pings. I already found the System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping but this didn't work so well, because it always sais timeout. even if i raise the timeout to more than 1s. i tested it in my console and i get good results. just when launching it with android it crashs.

---

maybe you'll find this interesting: TcpClient.Connect does work. BeginConnect doesn't. "an address incompatible with the requested protocol was used"...
well Connect is fine but i need to define a timeout, because i want to break if the server is offline.

Comment: For a  cross-platform solution, you can use an `TCPClient.BeginConnect`|`EndConnect` and wrap it in a `Stopwatch`, my answer here can be modified to do what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44117888/4984832 For a "true" (ICMP) ping on iOS: https://github.com/xamarin/XamarinComponents/tree/master/iOS/SimplePing and search SO for Android ping to see how to execute an external  ping process.

Comment: If your ping takes more than one second there probably is some error in your configuration or something like this.

Comment: sadly i even tried doing a TCP Client. but no success here too. it crashs at creation of my TCPClient.
and i want a crossplatform solution, so i don't have to write the same code 3 times. 
i mean otherwise i could've used android studio XD

Answer (score 0):

So for everyone who has problems with TcpClient.BeginConnect, too, just do a little trick:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
Task.Run(() =>
{
    client.Connect(host, port);
});
Task.Delay(100).Wait();
```

then you can access the client.Connected property to see if it has connected in that time.
Still don't know why my BeginConnect does not work.. or why even Connect didn't worked 10 minutes before... maybe i misspelled something but yeah :)