# CrossConnectivity check IP address of server if reachable

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am using James Montemagno's Connectivity Plugin to check if the IP address of my server is reachable. I trying to ping the IP address but when I check the value of my variable it turns to false. I am using XAMPP as my server. Even if a use a legitimate website like google.com the result is still false. I also added the necessary permissions

```
var isReachable = await CrossConnectivity.Current.IsReachable("192.168.120.10", 30000); //Result: false
```

Comment: I'd be interested in what Fiddler shows.

Comment: Mobile Platform? Physical device or simulator/emulator?

Comment: @SushiHangover device and emulator both are not working

Comment: Its a known issue, you can track progress [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ConnectivityPlugin/issues/145)

Comment: @LawrenceAgulto Since Shan noted that there is an open issue for that, you can do a port check, just adjust to only test the port(s) you are interested in:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44117888/4984832